# How to debug a VS Code extension when loaded from VSIX?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a vs code extension (currently private), and it runs fine when I run it via the VS Code debugger, (i.e., a "Launch Extension" target in my launch.json).  However, when I install the extension from a vsix file, the extension never activates.

Here's what I tried:

- View elements & commands show up, which implies the package.json is being read correctly.
- I placed `vscode.window.showInformationMessage(...)` statements in my `extension.js` and `extension.js`'s `activate()` methods.  I see expected output when I launch via VS Code debugger, but not when installed via vsix file.
- I changed the activation events to include `"onLanguage:javascript"`, hoping that opening a js file would cause my extension to activate, but it didn't.

A few questions:

- Any suggestions on what is going on here?
- Any suggestions on how to debug this?
- Any instructions on how I can attach a debugger?

Comment: Can you show your code? We cannot help unless we can see what you have written.

Comment: OK, so the trick to debugging situations like this is to bring up the chrome dev tools in the running instance of VS Code (Help menu, toggle development tools).  In this case, module deps were listed in `devDependencies` instead of `dependencies` section.  This is readily apparent when CDT is opened.

Comment: @MikeKaufman you are talking about the Console, right? Anything else you can do with the dev tools for an extension installed from VSIX? For example, I even fail to open (let alone set a breakpoint in) a .js file...